# Selenium WebDriver Exception The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL xyz Timed out after x seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit

So I am trying to set up a Selenium Testing Suite using C# and NUnit. Everything appeared to be working okay until my test durations started to be > 6 mins in length. Currently now any tests over 6 min end with the error as stated in the title. ***"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52821/session/f88e9cd6e93e8a3ef98796aaf87d14dd/url timed out after 90 seconds."***

The pages being tested however are all live production websites, nothing being tested is on a localhost.

So far I have tried increasing the default command timeout to various intervals including 30, 60, 90, 120, and 180 seconds this only makes it take longer for the test to report the error. Some times the test runs for 6 mins and stops other times 13 mins or anywhere in between. often it will get to the last page of the test even and throw the error there. The weird thing is if i split the pages up it runs okay. However when the test fails in this way, the chromedriver does not exit and the page remains open with the refresh thinggy spinning like its waiting for a request.

I have looked at literally every other related question on here and reddit and they all either seem to resolve themselves (like it just went away) or have some work around that just kinda doesn't actually solve the issue but allows them to still test. I want to know wtf this is happening.

My chrome browser is up to date version: Version 100.0.4896.127 the chromedriver is the most updated version as well for the 100.*** versioning of chrome. I reinstalled both and same issue. All the Nuget packages I use are also up to date.

I tried geckodriver with firefox and the issue is also there.

I am unsure if this is a selenium issue, or an issue with the design of my testing suite, or even an issue with my pc cause it does freeze sometimes. so I will include everything i think is relevant.

I have been using the singleton approach (just fyi)
**Code**

*Setup*

```
[SetUpFixture]
    [TestFixture]
    public class Setup
    {
        IWebDriver driver;        

        //Runs before ANY test is run
        //provies a place to set up configs for a testing env
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void RunBeforeAllTests()
        {
            driver = WebDriverSingleton.GetInstance();      
        }

        //Will run after every test has been completed
        //clean up
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void RunAfterAllTests()
        {                              
            WebDriverSingleton.Terminate();
        }
    }
```

*Driver*

```
public class Driver
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        public Driver()
        {
            this.driver = WebDriverSingleton.GetInstance();            
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            driver = WebDriverSingleton.GetInstance();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }
        public void End()
        {
            driver.Close();
            //WebDriverSingleton.Terminate();
        }
        public void GoTo(string url)
        {
            this.driver.Url = url;
        }

        public IWebElement GetElementBy(string method, string selector)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000));
            try
            {
                switch (method)
                {
                    case "tag":
                        return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName(selector)));
                    case "xpath":
                        return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(selector)));
                    case "css":
                        return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(selector)));
                    case "id":
                        return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(selector)));
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.Fail("FAILURE! last page: " + this.driver.Url + "\n" + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            
        }

        public string GetTextBy(string method, string selector)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
            //{
                // didnt seem to work :/
            //    PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            //};
        
            switch (method)
            {
                case "tag":
                    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName(selector))).Text;
                case "xpath":
                    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(selector))).Text;
                case "css":
                    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(selector))).Text;
                case "id":
                    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(selector))).Text;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }    
    }
```

*singleton*

```
public sealed class WebDriverSingleton
    {
        private static IWebDriver instance = null;
        private WebDriverSingleton() { }

        public static IWebDriver GetInstance()
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                ChromeOptions options = new();
                options.BrowserVersion = "100.0.4896.6000";
                options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
                instance = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
            }

            return instance;
        }
        
        public static void Terminate()
        {
            instance.Close();
            instance.Quit();
            instance.Dispose();
            instance = null;
        }

    }
```

*test class where issue stems*

```
[TestFixture]
    public class PowerSupplyTests
    {
        readonly Driver driver = new Driver();
        private readonly Common Common = new();        
        public List<ProductPage> ProductPages { get; set; }
        public string TestDomain { get; set; }
        public string CurrLang { get; set; }
        // for now only 1 language comparison can be run at a time
        public List<string> LanguagesToTest = new List<string>()
        {
            /*"DE","ES",  */ "FR"/*, "IT"*/
        };
        public List<string> ProductPageListOldTechSpecTable = new List<string>()
        {
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-1-phase-xt.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-3-phase.shtml",
            //"/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-3-phase.shtml"
        };
        public List<string> ProductPageListBasicDataTable = new List<string>() 
        {
            "/products/industrial-din-rail-power-supplies.shtml",            
        };
        public List<string> ProductPageListSingleProduct = new List<string>()
        {
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-high-input.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-12dc-12dc-8-29050078.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-12dc-24dc-5-23201318.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-12dc-15-29046088.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-12dc-20-28667218.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-1.3-pt-29095758.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-1.3-sc-29045978.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-10-29046018.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-2.5-29095768.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-2.5-sc-29045988.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-20-29046028.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-3.5-28667478.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-3.8-pt-29095778.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-3.8-sc-29045998.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-40-28667898.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-24dc-5-29046008.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-48dc-10-29046118.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-48dc-20-28666958.shtml",//here for IT
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-1ac-48dc-5-29046108.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-12dc-8-23201158.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-10-23200928.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-10-co-23205558.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-20-23201028.shtml",//
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-20-co-23205688.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-5-23200348.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-24dc-5-co-23205428.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-24dc-48dc-5-23201288.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-48dc-24dc-5-23201448.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-48dc-48dc-5-29050088.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-60-72dc-24dc-10-29050098.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-60-72dc-24dc-10-co-29050118.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-96-110dc-24dc-10-29050108.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/quint-ps-96-110dc-24dc-10-co-29050128.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-12dc-1.5-28685678.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-12dc-1.5-fl-28685548.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-12dc-1-28685388.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-12dc-3-28685708.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-12dc-5-28685838.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-15dc-4-28686198.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-0.5-28685968.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-0.75-28686358.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-0.75-fl-28686228.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-1.75-28686488.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-2.5-28686518.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-3.5-29049458.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-3.8-c2lps-28686778.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-24dc-4.2-28686648.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-48dc-2-28686808.shtml",//
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-5dc-16.5-28685418.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-1ac-5dc-2-23205138.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/step-ps-48ac-24dc-0.5-28687168.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-dc-dc-high-input.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-12dc-10-29031588.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-12dc-5-c2lps-29031578.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-10-29031498.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-10-b+d-29031458.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-20-29031518.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-3-c2lps-29031478.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-5-29031488.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-24dc-5-b+d-29031448.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-48dc-10-29031608.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/trio-ps-2g-1ac-48dc-5-29031598.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-2-phase.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-dc-dc.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-12dc-100w-29029978.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-12dc-30w-29029988.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-15dc-100w-29030028.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-15dc-30w-29030008.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-15dc-55w-29030018.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-100w-29029938.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-150w-29043768.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-240w-29043728.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-30w-29029918.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-60w-29029928.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-24dc-90w-c2lps-29029948.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-48dc-100w-29029968.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-48dc-60w-29029958.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-5dc-25w-29043748.shtml",
            "/products/industrial-power-supply/uno-ps-1ac-5dc-40w-29043758.shtml"
        };

        [SetUp]
        public void Start()
        {
            driver.Start();
            ProductPages = new List<ProductPage>();
        }
        [Test]
        public void TestAllPages()
        {
            LanguagesToTest.ForEach((lang) =>
            {
                CurrLang = lang;
                switch (lang)
                {
                    case "DE":
                        TestDomain = Common.GermanDomain;
                        break;
                    case "ES":
                        TestDomain = Common.SpanishDomain;
                        break;
                    case "FR":
                        TestDomain = Common.FrenchDomain;
                        break;
                    case "IT":
                        TestDomain = Common.ItalianDomain;
                        break;
                }
                ProductPageListBasicDataTable.ForEach((p) =>
                {
                    ProductPage newPage = new ProductPage(driver, p);
                    TestDocumentationTab(newPage);
                    TestOrderDetailsTabBasicTable(newPage);
                });
                ProductPageListOldTechSpecTable.ForEach((p) =>
                {
                    ProductPage newPage = new ProductPage(driver, p);
                    TestDocumentationTab(newPage);
                    TestOrderDetailsTabOldSpecTable(newPage);
                });
                ProductPageListSingleProduct.ForEach((p) =>
                {
                    ProductPage newPage = new ProductPage(driver, p);
                    TestDocumentationTab(newPage);
                    TestOrderDetailTabSingleProduct(newPage);
                });
            });
        }    

        public void TestDocumentationTab(ProductPage productPage)
        {
            productPage.GoToProduct(Common.EnglishDomain);
            productPage.OpenDocumentationTab();
            string enSrc = productPage.CaptureIframeSrc("idoc");
            enSrc = enSrc.Substring(enSrc.IndexOf("products"));            
            productPage.GoToProduct(TestDomain);
            productPage.OpenDocumentationTab();            
            string comparisonSrc = productPage.CaptureIframeSrc("idoc");
            comparisonSrc = comparisonSrc.Substring(comparisonSrc.IndexOf("products"));
            if (!enSrc.Equals(comparisonSrc))
                Assert.Fail("Page " + productPage.PageUrl + " documentation sources do not match! \n "+ enSrc + "\n" + comparisonSrc + " failure found in lang: " + CurrLang);            
        }

        public void TestOrderDetailsTabBasicTable(ProductPage productPage)
        {
            List<Product> enProducts = new List<Product>();
            List<Product> comparisonProducts = new List<Product>();
            productPage.GoToProduct(Common.EnglishDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();            
            enProducts = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetProductsFromBasicDataTable();            
            
            productPage.GoToProduct(TestDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();
            comparisonProducts = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetProductsFromBasicDataTable();
            if (enProducts.Count != comparisonProducts.Count)
                Assert.Fail("Product Table Quantites do not match!");
            for (int i = 0; i < enProducts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!enProducts[i].Equals(comparisonProducts[i]))
                    Assert.Fail("Product Tables do not match! \n" + "Failure occurred on page: " + productPage.PageUrl + "\nIn Lang: " + CurrLang);
            }            
        }
        public void TestOrderDetailsTabOldSpecTable(ProductPage productPage)
        {
            List<Product> enProducts = new List<Product>();
            List<Product> testProducts = new List<Product>();
            productPage.GoToProduct(Common.EnglishDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();
            enProducts = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetProductsFromTechSpecDataTable();
            productPage.GoToProduct(TestDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();
            testProducts = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetProductsFromTechSpecDataTable();
            if (enProducts.Count != testProducts.Count)
                Assert.Fail("Product Table Quantites do not match!");
            for (int i = 0; i < enProducts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!enProducts[i].Equals(testProducts[i]))
                    Assert.Fail( CurrLang + " Product Tables do not match!");
            }
        }

        public void TestOrderDetailTabSingleProduct(ProductPage productPage)
        {
            Product enProduct = new Product();
            Product testProducts = new Product();
            productPage.GoToProduct(Common.EnglishDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();
            enProduct = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetSingleProductFromTab();
            productPage.GoToProduct(TestDomain);
            productPage.OpenOrderingDetailsTab();
            testProducts = productPage.OrderDetailsTabModel.GetSingleProductFromTab();
            Assert.IsNotNull(enProduct.productId);
            Assert.IsNotNull(testProducts.productId);
            if (!enProduct.Equals(testProducts))
                Assert.Fail("Products Do Not Match!\nEN: " + enProduct.productId[0] + "\n" + CurrLang + ": " + testProducts.productId[0]);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void End()
        {
            driver.End();
        }
    }
```

finally the error log

```
 TestAllPages
   Source: powerSupplyTests.cs line 125
   Duration: 11.1 min

  Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52821/session/f88e9cd6e93e8a3ef98796aaf87d14dd/url timed out after 90 seconds.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 90 seconds elapsing.
  ----> System.TimeoutException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52821/session/f88e9cd6e93e8a3ef98796aaf87d14dd/window timed out after 90 seconds.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 90 seconds elapsing.
  ----> System.TimeoutException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

  Stack Trace: 
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.set_Url(String value)
Driver.GoTo(String url) line 36
ProductPage.GoToProduct(String baseUrl) line 48
PowerSupplyTests.TestDocumentationTab(ProductPage productPage) line 172
PowerSupplyTests.<TestAllPages>b__19_3(String p) line 160
List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
PowerSupplyTests.<TestAllPages>b__19_0(String lang) line 157
List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
PowerSupplyTests.TestAllPages() line 127
--TaskCanceledException
HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
--TimeoutException
--TaskCanceledException
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--IOException
AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--SocketException
--TearDown
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.Close()
Driver.End() line 31
PowerSupplyTests.End() line 237
--TaskCanceledException
HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
--TimeoutException
--TaskCanceledException
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--IOException
AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--SocketException
```

Comment: So servers have limits and close connection when limits are reached.  When connection is closed your client may not be getting the closure and eventually a time out is reached.

Comment: but wouldn't extending the commandTimeout account for this? i set it up to 3 mins, and when i navigate to the page in another browser like seconds later there is no issue with the page.

Comment: No.  If server limits is size and you exceed a 10M size timeout wouldn't matter.

Comment: I see, so lets say I have access to all the servers( IIS ) how could i verify your theory? would the logs tell me that this is happening?

Comment: Not sure about logs.  HTTP(s) uses TCP as the transport layer.  So if you look at a sniffer and see a [FIN] that the lower layer TCP closed the connection.  Normally the transport layer doesn't let the HTTP know when the connection closes.

Comment: It seems to think you're running a remote driver here... grid on localhost...  your driver doesn't seem to be initialized as remote and it's running some socket stuff that should only be available to a remote driver.  CDP or Bidi?  From the code it looks like you are running the tests on the same machine as the code...  (in that case localhost is used by the webdriver to communicate with the browser via wire protocol and I don't think the socks methods would be available...)  Try setting the CDP stuff to NOOP.

Comment: @pcalkins no I am testing websites live on the internet. Running selenium from my laptop

Comment: what is value of Environment.CurrentDirectory?  As a side note you may want to avoid using driver.close()... I was finding some issues with that where it was leaving orphaned drivers open, and you've got a /window command in that stack trace.  Just use the .quit() method to teardown.

Comment: now that I look again, looks like you might only be using .close() right now... you commented out the singleton teardown... that definitely won't quit the driver.  It will only attempt to close the driver's current browser window/tab.  That will leave orphaned webdrivers and probably some issues with sessionIDs in future runs.

Comment: @pcalkins the singleton terminate method is still called in the oneTimeTearDown method in setup is that not sufficient?

Comment: also will answer you other question in a moment just running again with some small changes

Comment: @pcalkins the directory is c:\\me\\Desktop\\Perle\\perlewebsite_automation_testing\\perlewebsite_automation_testing\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0"

Comment: seems like that path should include "chromedriver.exe"... (I usually work in Java, so C# binding might be a little different in that regard...)  I would avoid using .close() method altogether if you see "chromedriver.exe" running in your processes when it should be closed.  (or multiple...) The quit() method should close the browser and exit/dispose of the webdriver.  If the singleton teardown is called, then you are calling close() twice... 2nd call will fail if only one tab/window is open.... then exception might cause your quit() to fail.

Comment: As for the original exception here... the timeout issue... it sounds like the driver is in nomans land...  if you are opening/closing new tabs, you'll want to check to be sure you haven't left the driver in a windowhandle that no longer exists.  (ex: open new tab, switch driver to it, do some things there, close tab... forget to switch the driver back to an existing tab/handle, then try to do some things...)

Comment: no tabs are being opening only navigating to other pages via driver.url = ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably this behaviour was introduced in the new (100th) version of Chrome. Try to use older version of Chrome and chromedriver.

Comment: See I was wondering this too. Since it started happening after chrome updated. but I thought since i updated the driver and the driver packages to all be the same version it would be fine. Like others i have implemented a slight workaround and it appears to be running okay but I still would love to know for certain the actual cause :/

Comment: Yes, the problem was with different versions of Chrome and chromedriver. After synchronizing the versions, the problem was solved. Tested under WIndows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I think this is related to more recent versions of chromedriver... I may have seen this a little earlier as well, maybe v98+.

Comment: I don't think I ever saw this in geckodriver, though (I'm running 0.30..0)...  is it still happening there?  I'd also like to get to the cause of this.  Were you using 0.31.0?  Rolling back chromedriver and setting environment variable to bypass the version check seems to be working for me so far...

Comment: It's possible this is something that's fixed in Selenium 4.1.3.  (I'm currently using 4.1.2)  Related to this issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10345  I'll run some tests to try to confirm.  (It's difficult because it's been somewhat random...)  Anyone see these kinds of socket timeout issues on 4.1.3?

Comment: That wasn't it... possibly a bug in chromedriver v101... not real sure as I'm pretty sure I've seen it in previous versions too.  Had to rollback the driver to fix (went to chromedriver v89, and bypassed browser/driver version check)  My hunch it is something to do with CDP or the new host validation stuff.  Doesn't seem like many people are experiencing this issue, so there's probably another variable at play.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like I've found some solution that make work for somebody.
So I've ran 100+ test cases with Selenium with usage of TeamCity Agent. Almost every time atleast one test failed with such an error:

> 09:30:12      OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown
> exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote
> WebDriver server for URL
> http://localhost:10458/session/e050c5112562c1539c7518353fa3cce2/element.
> The exception message was: No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it. (localhost:10458) 09:30:12
> ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:10458)
> 09:30:12     ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've checked the proxy on server which run the tests, firewall, set config that most of the time, people described as a fix. For example:

```
   "--no-sandbox",
    "--proxy-server='direct://'",
    "--proxy-bypass-list=*",
```

But it didn't solve any problem. So at the time I was using .NET 6.0 With up to date chromedriver ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63.

What worked was the **downgrade of .NET 6.0 to .NET 5.0**

Comment: Downgrading frameworks does not constitute a solution; by definition it does not work for anyone trying to test modern code.